# rooting Samsung captivate with the new gingerbread release

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, 2.3-gingerbread, rooting, updates

I just got a message from my cell provider that the official Gingerbread release is out for the Samsung Captivate. I recently rooted my phone so I could install non market apps. Will I have to un root to upgrade, and after I have is there a tool that will let me re root? All the Google searches I did brought up old results.

Answer (score 1):

To install non market apps, u dont need to root your phone . :\ 
I dont think u need to unroot your device for updating it through samsung kies. 
But after updating to Gingerbread, your device is automatically unrooted.

Comment: On a Captivate you actually did originally need to root (or use a PC application like the [Sideload Wonder Machine](http://forums.androidcentral.com/android-sideload-wonder-machine/76171-android-central-sideload-wonder-machine-v-1-2-a.html)). AT&T prevented you from sideloading apps by default, though I think the 2.3 update lifted that restriction.